# Image loads in simulator but not on device (Titanium Studio Android)

Tags: android, ios, imageview, emulation, titanium-mobile

I'm new to Titanium Studio. I put all images(png format) in Images directory inside Resources folder (Resources\Images).

When I set the image of an ImageView by mentioning the image name with path like given below,

```
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({Image: 'Images/myimage.png', top: 20, height: 100, width: 100, left: 30});
```

I saw that it works fine in emulator, but not in my device. When I tested the same code in Iphone Simulator and IPod touch, it worked fine. Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the sample under the name "kitchensink" project, that will easily answer your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator is not case-sensitive when it comes to file names, but the device is - make sure it's nothing to do with case.

Comment: Good tip, this saved me today!